Decoding transaction instructions in order to listen to outputs of those transactions
currently working on a project and it's all coming together nicely apart from this part. So what I want to achieve is listening to instructions, so I'm already subsribed and listening to the address that I'm working with but having trouble trying to figure out how to listen to the outputs of the instructions. So what I'm getting are the program addresses that the transaction is interacting with but I need the output of the interactions if that makes sense?
Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4188 of 52167 compute units',
  'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
  'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 20301 of 67997 compute units',
  'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success',

So as you can see those are just the default addresses but I need the custom one's. The 'output'.
Any idea's on how to achieve this are welcome and thanks in advance!

If you want to get more information about the transaction, you'll need to fetch it with getTransaction. I'm assuming you're using logsSubscribe to get updates, so when you notice some logs that are interesting, you can take the signature from the update, fetch the transaction, and investigate whatever is interesting to you.
More information about getTransaction at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction
